# How can I import data from csv file attached in resources to my table in pgadmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin-4

```
COPY PUBLIC. "Science_Class"(Enrollment_no", "name", "marks") FROM 'c:\users\HP\Student.csv' CSV HEADER ;
```

I'm trying to import the Student. Csv file into the science_class table so I can add other data from it but keep getting an error 'couldn't open file for reading :Permission denied

Comment: 1) This is a permissions problem as `COPY` runs as the server user and that user obviously does not have permissions on the file. See [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)  2) `pgAdmin` has a built in method to achieve the same thing, see here [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.13/import_export_data.html).

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver I've been able to import it